# Error installing passenger: invalid gem format (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

While attempting to install passenger via `gem install passenger`, I receive the following error:

```
Fetching: passenger-5.0.21.gem (3793B)<br>
ERROR:  Error installing passenger:
    invalid gem format for /home/daffolap-198/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/cache/passenger-5.0.21.gem
```

I have already deleted the passenger-5.0.21.gem file inside the cache folder, but that did not resolve the issue.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It was  downloading permission issue , Once I got full permission for download after that I deleted the passenger gem file from cache folder then run gem install passenger and it has been installed successfully.